# Puppeteer not working in headless mode with chromium

Tags: google-chrome, raspberry-pi, chromium, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer 1.20.0 with Chromium-browser v74 on Raspberry pi running Raspbian 10. Using the example code from Puppeteer Github page works as expected when running Puppeteer in headless disabled, however, if I try to run it in headless mode I get this error and it crashes.

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Navigation failed because
>   browser has disconnected.

**My Code:**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
        executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
        headless: true
    });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://youtube.com');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

The same code works as expected both headless and non-headless in another Debian 10 machine. They both are running Puppeteer 1.20.0 the only difference is the Debian machine is running Google-chrome 77 whereas the Raspbian is running Chromium-browser 74.

**Edit:**

I also tried the puppeteer-core version 1.13.0 which is the recommended version for chromium 74 but it also didn't work in headless mode.

Answer (score 1):

I finally was able to run puppeteer... but not on Raspbian buster. Here are the details of the environment where I successfully ran puppeteer:

- Linux raspberrypi 4.19.66-v7+ #1253 SMP Thu Aug 15 11:49:46 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
- Raspbian Stretch (2019-04-08-raspbian-stretch)
- NodeJS v12.10.0 & npm v6.10.3 (from nodesource)
- **puppeteer-core@1.11.0**
- `chromium-browser` **Chromium 72.0.3626.121** Built on Raspbian , running on Raspbian 9.11

I did NOT use the downloaded chromium from `puppeteer`, I used the one that came with raspbian and added the `"executablePath"` config so I can only use `"puppeteer-core"`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think it doesn't matter which Raspbian version you are running. The problem is with Chromium 74 in that comes with Raspbian 10 is broken and can't be used with puppeteer in headless mode. How did find Chromium 72? same performance as 74?

Comment: I haven't measured the performance between both. I usually run a script that will scrape around 200-300 urls 3 times a day and have to limit the number of chromium browser instances running at the same time due to the RPi capacity and cpu temp. When running on the RPi, the whole scraping thing takes between 25 and 30 minutes, on a laptop (MBP i7) takes less than 15 minutes but is also using another version of chromium and puppeteer

Comment: @erickpeniche: Can you supply terminal console to install puppeteer-core, chromium-browser and sample code? I tried but wasn't success.

Answer (score 0):

Puppeteer is only guaranteed to work with the version of chromium that it is bundled with (puppeteer rather than puppeteer-core). So you would probably have better luck running an older version of puppeteer that is built for chromium 74.

Comment: I also tried the puppeteer-core version 1.13.0 which is the recommended version for chromium 74 but it also didn't work in headless mode.

Answer (score 0):

Puppeter comes with compatible chromium..in node_modules/puppeter/ look for .local-chromium  if you don't find it I suggest delete node_modules and hit "npm i puppeteer"